# Using Maxima, how can I combine two lists into one nested list?

Tags: matrix, maxima

I have one list of x-values and another for y-values. I would like these arranged in a 2 column matrix or a nested list (which I can easily turn into a matrix). In Mathematica, this is accomplished using Thread[x-values, y-values], but I can find no similar Maxima function.

I'm starting with these two lists,

```
Tx:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

Ty:[86,85,84,89,85,89,87,85,82,85];
```

and manually making this,

```
ListT: [[1,86],[2,85],[3,84],[4,89],[5,85],[6,89],[7,87],[8,85],[9,82],[10,85]];
```

so I can create a matrix using

```
MatrixT: apply('matrix,ListT);
```

Is there a 'quick' way to do this because my real data set has hundreds of data points that come to me in this fashion.?

Answer (score 3):

I think an easy way to do that is to create a matrix which has 2 rows and many columns, and then transpose it to 2 columns and many rows:

```
MatrixT: transpose (matrix (Tx, Ty));
```

There are at least two other ways I can think of:

```
ListT: map (lambda ([a, b], [a, b]), Tx, Ty);
MatrixT: apply (matrix, ListT);
```

and

```
ListT: makelist ([Tx[i], Ty[i]], i, 1, length(Tx));
MatrixT: apply (matrix, ListT);
```

I use `transpose` pretty often to go back and forth between row-oriented and column-oriented variables. E.g., let's say you have a `mymatrix3` with 3 columns and you want variables X, Y, and Z to be assigned the columns. You can say

```
[X, Y, Z]: args (transpose (mymatrix3));
```

since `args(<some matrix>)` returns a list of the rows of the matrix, and `[X, Y, Z]: <some list of 3 things>` represents parallel assignment.

May I ask for what purpose you are using Maxima? I am always interested to hear what people are working on. (I'm a Maxima developer and project administrator.)

Answer (score 0):

I only found this way:

```
(%i1) Tx:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
(%o1)                   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
(%i2) Ty:[86,85,84,89,85,89,87,85,82,85];
(%o2)              [86, 85, 84, 89, 85, 89, 87, 85, 82, 85]
(%i3) ListT:makelist([Tx[i],Ty[i]],i,1,length(Tx));
(%o3) [[1, 86], [2, 85], [3, 84], [4, 89], [5, 85], [6, 89], [7, 87], [8, 85], [9, 82], [10, 85]]
```